# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed-rma.mv

Tags: r

I'm trying to execute the following code in R for a 3-level meta-analysis

full.model<-rma.mv(FisherZ, 
                   varZ, 
                   random = list(~ 1 | id, 
                                 ~ 1 | Study_ID), 
                   tdist = TRUE, 
                   data = madata,
                   method = "REML")

But I'm getting an error
Error in if (is.vector(V) || nrow(V) == 1L || ncol(V) == 1L) V <- diag(as.vector(V),  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to varZ.
The line `if (is.vector(V) || nrow(V) == 1L || ncol(V) == 1L) V <- diag(as.vector(V)` attempts to perform tests on varZ (with V= varZ).

if varZ is empty or Null you'll get errors. If it's not a matrix you'll get error as well.

You have to ensure it is a matrix with `is.matrix(varZ)`.
If `False`, try to cast it as a matrix with `varZ <- as.matrix(varZ)`

To be castable to a matrix, varZ needs to be a 2 D object filled with only one type of variable. I your case it would be doubles, as the function you use expects a variance/covariance matrix

Comment: FizherZ is the Z transformation of the effect size, and varZ is the variance of this z transformed effect size

Comment: Are you sure it is a non empty matrix ?

Comment: Should I do something about this: If it's not a matrix you'll get error as well?

Comment: it has no missing value, but I don't know if its a matrix or not.

Comment: you can check with 
    is.matrix(varZ).

if it returns FALSE, type
    typeof(varZ) to know what it is

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right, it was a double, I changed it to matrix and now it works.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit my answer above so that the answer is more general for future people coming to this thread